# А что теперь нельзя бесплатно тестировать google maps api?

Tags: google-maps-api

А что теперь нельзя бесплатно тестировать google maps api? Они предлагают Включить оплату в Google Cloud Platform...

Answer (score 2):

У Google Maps API остались бесплатные квоты для только для мобильных устройств. Зато он дают $300 кредита каждый месяц на ваш биллинг. 
Полный список цен вы можете найтит [тут](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/?_ga=2.53136936.1021294915.1578572995-642630602.1573038153). Также есть специальный [калькулятор](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/) для прогнозирования стоимости.

Comment: Честно сказать зря они так сделали. Я например хотел потестить, насколько их решение подходит к моей задаче, но теперь я по умолчанию не буду их рассматривать, а значит не буду их реальным клиентом в будущем.

Comment: Если есть какие-то бесплатные подобные решения (пусть и частично бесплатно или с ограничениями) и вы их знаете, буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь напишет сюда о них. Спасибо!

Comment: @ВикторВасильев попробуйте applemaps, mapbox или tomtom